# How to pre-install sbt on an AWS EC2 instance (via user data)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, scala, amazon-ec2, sbt, sdkman

What I tried to far without success inside the AWS EC2 user data section:

```
#!/bin/bash    
sudo curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash

#!/bin/bash
sudo curl --output-dir "/home/ec2-user/" -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

The problem is that the **.sdkman folder** in above cases is not stored inside /home/ec2-user/.sdkman but rather **always stored inside the root folder** under /.sdkman for an automated EC2 instance launch with user data. (Manual installation via cmd on the other hand would work)

Which fails to make following next command to install sbt via user data:

```
source "/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

---

(Accepting that the .sdkman folder is stored inside the root folder) I also tried instead to use:

```
source ".sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"

source "/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

but this does not work and returns following error:

```
find: ‘/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/src’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/ext’: No such file or directory
touch: cannot touch ‘/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/var/delay_upgrade’: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/ec2-user/.sdkman/var/candidates: No such file or directory
-bash: __sdkman_echo_debug: command not found
```

As it looks like with the source command am I not able to go below /home/ec2-user/ as it's always added back to the path.

---

Further resources:
https://sdkman.io/install

---

AWS EC2 Instance: Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM) - Kernel 5.10 // t3a.xlarge

Any help on how I can install sbt on an AWS EC2 instance automated via user data is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ec2 UserData will execute as the root user. if you want to execute the user data as a non-root user, please follow the below format. p.s - all command has to be nested under single command, if you break into multiple lines, then the next line will be executed under the root user.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
su ec2-user bash -c "curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash; source "/home/ec2-user/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether this may help you or not.I think you can install vim yum. The following commands may work for you in user data.

```
#!/bin/bash 
curl https://bintray.com/sbt/rpm/rpm | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/bintray-sbt-rpm.repo
sudo yum install sbt
```

[link](https://www.linuxtutorial.co.uk/install-sbt-on-amazon-linux/) for above steps

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/install-software.html

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Bintray as far as I am aware of does not offer their service anymore since the 01 May 2021, which leads by entering above command to: "...<head><title>403 Forbidden</title></head>..."   https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/  If you found a different way to solve this problem above please let me know